# Orchard Core Built in search versus Azure Search

Tags: graphql, orchardcms, azure-cognitive-search

I am new to CMS search abilities and Azure search. I am looking at CMS options and was looking at Orchard Core CMS and saw it had Lucene search and GraphQL for searching via Headless CMS implementation as well. I also see Azure search services out in Azure. I am confused on if I should simply use the built-in search Orchard Core CMS already has or if Azure search is much better and what it can offer me. Clueless here....

Answer (score 1):

Orchard Core as of now uses Lucene directly. The only drawback of using Lucene directly is that it doesn't scale as well as an Azure Search for example which is a distributed service.

The Lucene implementation in OC has been inspired by ElasticSearch. You can create Lucene Queries which are using quite the same syntax as ElasticSearch Queries. In fact we try to use the ElasticSearch documentation to replicate as much as we can the same Query syntax.

Right now the plan is to eventually support Reddis + ElasticSearch as distributed services but I've heard nothing about Azure Search. Remember that ElasticSearch is probably a little more polyvalent as it can also be installed on premise.